# Product Attribute - Multiple Select Not Saving

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, products

Hi I have products with a fair few custom attributes which are all working fine. I have two Multiple selects however that do not save what I enter in them!

All other text fields, dropdowns etc all save fine but it doesn't matter if I select one or ten options on the multiple selects they don't save, save and continue or just save, it doesn't make a difference!

Has anyone had this occur or does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: did you create this multi select attribute directly from admin or by any script ?

Comment: Try to do a cache flush

Comment: Hi, I tried clearing cache and index with no luck. It is just the default admin area way of doing it no custom scripts used :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your `eav_attribute` table for that attribute. The `backend_type` should be `text` (not `varchar`), and the `backend_model` should be `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend`